# How to improve check spelling performance, using Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, nlp, spell-checking

I'm using Apache Spark for NLP (natural language processing) with LDA.
And before run LDA Model, I have a module calling "CorrectEmoticon"
I have a dictionary for this purpose, and this file look like:

```
:) \t smile
;) \t blink
...
```

After that, to apply this dictionary into my module I try:

```
public static String correctSentence(String sentence) {
   String rplace = sentence.replaceAll("[,.]", "");
   String[] split = rplace.split(" ");
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (String inputStr : split) {
       sb.append(correctWord(inputStr));
       sb.append(" ");
   }
   return sb.toString();
}

private static String correctWord(String word) {
    word = getDefination(word);
    return word;
}
public static String getDefination(String word) {
    List<String> foundList = dict.lookup(word.trim().toLowerCase());
    if (foundList != null && !foundList.isEmpty()){
        return foundList.get(0);
    } 
    return word;
}
```

And variable dict is:

```
private static JavaPairRDD<String, String> dict;
```

"dict" is contain value of emoticon and emoticon's meaning.

But, if I use this algorithm, it run very slow. 
So, can you help me to correct this algorithm to improve performance..
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are making dictionary lookups for every token you process. This is far from optimal. Ideally, you can construct a character-based dictionary graph and use it as a [finite state automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Example:

[image]

This is a somewhat involved solution, but you can also use a number of simpler heuristics to make it faster too, such as create a character set of all your first emoji characters, token length restrictions, clever regular expressions (if your emojis follow a pattern), match letter-only tokens (i.e. clearly no emojis) etc.